# Python: How to create File objects from a string?

Tags: python, xml, unit-testing, file

I am currently trying to unit test a module that parses and validates an `XML` file against a `.XSD` schema that I created. I want to be able to test a bunch of different `XML` files, but don't want to have to make a bunch of different `XML`s. I was wondering if there is a way to simply use a `string` to create a File object that can be passed into the function I am testing.

An example might be:

```
File('<test><text>This is a test xml file used for testing</text></test>')
```

I just don't know the exact syntax to do it and can't find it. Thanks!

Comment: I think you want `io.StringIO`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use StringIO for this!

```py
import io
f = io.StringIO("<test><text>Thats a test!</text></test>")
```

Is just the same as

```py
f = open("test.xml", "r", encoding="utf-8")
```

But without having to have an actual file!

So it should fulfil your needs

Comment: This worked great! Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Your welcome! Please press the check mark beside the answer to accept it.